# Как скроллинг от трекпада преобразовать в скроллинг от мышки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, прокрутка

В общем на сайте осуществляется скроллинг по компонентам, этому способствуют такие библиотеки как
[react scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) и [react-scroll-wheel-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-wheel-handler). То есть при скролле мышкой срабатывает некое событие:

```
function NavigateToTop() {
let newIndex = index - 1
if (newIndex < 0) {
  newIndex = 0
}
setIndex(newIndex)
scroller.scrollTo(position[newIndex], {
  duration: 800,
  smooth: 'easeInOutQuint',
})
```

}

Все в целом корректно работает, но проблема в том, что при скролле трекпадом от ноутбука функция отрабатывает некорректно. В основном наблюдается такая тенденция у макбуков, так как протестив на ноутбуках с OC Wondows всё отрабатывало правильно. И вот вопрос, как от этого избавится ?

Comment: Поясните и приведите пример неправильной работы и правильной для сравнения

Comment: Зниачит при пролистовании на Mac тачпаде необходимое событие не возникает.

Comment: @SwaD сделал для как пример этот проект https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-sound-u5zcz3?file=/src/App.js Это пример правильного скролла. При скролле трекпадом скролл остается как будто посередине, показать не могу, мака рядом нет